# The same file has two js files imported successively with import

Tags: reactjs

for example

```js
// a.jsx file
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useMount } from "utils";
useMount() // error 'useEffect' is not defined no-undef

// utils file, do not introduce useEffect in this file
export const useMount = (callback) => {
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log('I executed useMOunt');
   }, [])
}
```

My own understanding is that because useEffect has been introduced before useMount is introduced, shouldn't useEffect be found by searching through the scope chain when calling, why is there an undefined error, I hope someone can answer my question question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> useEffect not defined no-undef

is because of the second reason below

Reasons

**First--** the way you are importing the useMount from utils.
Assuming your a.jsx is present in the same directory as utils.jsx, you should import it like:

```
import { useMount } from "./utils.jsx";
```

This specifies that you are importing useMount from utils.jsx which is present in the same directory.

**Second--**
As you wrote:

> // utils file, do not introduce useEffect in this file

You will need useEffect in the utils file, and don't really need it in the a.jsx file *as basically the function useMount is written in the utils file* and it needs useEffect to perform the action.

Finally, the code working for me is:

utils.jsx:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export const useMount = (callback) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('I executed useMOunt');
    }, [])
 }
```

App.jsx:

```
import { useMount } from "./utils.jsx";

const App = () => {
  useMount();
  return (
    <div>
      Some text goes here...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Output on browser console:

[I executed useMOunt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nrvH.png)

---

And it doesn't work when my utils file is:

```
export const useMount = (callback) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('I executed useMOunt');
    }, [])
 }
```

giving the same error you are getting.

Pl, review my first answer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The code of the es6 module is in a separate scope, and the variables defined by a.jsx cannot be accessed in the utils module.

// compiled file, pseudocode

```js
const react = (function () {
     const useEffect = () => {}
     return {
        useEffect,
     }
})()

const utils = (function () {
     const useMount = (callback) => {
       useEffect(() => {
         console.log('I executed useMOunt');
       }, [])
     }
     return {
        useMount,
     }
})()

(function (useEffect, useMount) {
   useMount() // error
})(react.useEffectt, utils.useMount)
```